# Put to a particular line

Tags: vimrc

I would like to put the current text in a register onto line 10. How I am doing it now is yanking the text, then going up to that line and then pasting the text, but I'd like to stay on the current line. Is there a way to do something like:

```
12Gp " paste something onto line 12
```

**Update:** it looks like this is answered on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53115840/651174.

```
:copy 12
:t 12       " alias
```

Or:

```
:move 12    " move current line(s) to position
:m 12       " alias
```

Though it works on the current line(s) or a range, and doesn't necessarily paste what's in the register.

Comment: See `:help :put`.

Comment: @Ralf -- thanks. So `:12put` would out from the default register. Is there a way to do something like `:12put "a` ?

Comment: `:put=@a`, but `:put` adds a line. `setline()` (IIRC the name of the function) replaces the lines. See `:h functions()`, here are plenty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:put`.

To put the content of register `a` *below* line 12:

```
:12put a
```

To put the content of register `a` *before* line 12 add the exclamation mark:

```
:12put! a
```

BTW: Put can also be used with strings or variables:

```
:12put ="Below 12"
:let x="Also below 12"
:12put =x
```